# How to run Python script to run daily using apscheduler with flask?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I want test_job function to run everyday at 4 pm how can I do that? This code is working fine for the time interval.

```
from flask import Flask

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


app = Flask(__name__)

def test_job():
    print('I am working...')

@app.route('/')
def route():
    return 'flask'

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
job = scheduler.add_job(test_job, 'interval', seconds=3)
scheduler.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this

```py
job = scheduler.add_job(test_job, 'cron', day_of_week ='mon-sun', hour=16, minute=00)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to: https://crontab.guru/ and configure your required cron.
For Example your corn expression is:

```
cron = "0 16 * * *"
```

Call this then:

```
job = scheduler.add_job(func=<function-name>, trigger=CronTrigger.from_crontab(cron))
```

I do not have specific knowledge about flask but in fastapi there is "app startup event". If there is anything like this, pass the scheduler initialization and add job activities on that event-based route.